# Replace Devart DotConnect with MySQL Connector / Net - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mysql-connector, dotconnect

I am working on a Visual Studio 2010 Solution. This solution is a web-site comprised of multiple web apps (using JavaScript, ASP, etc.).

Every time I compile, I get an error message stating that my DotConnect trial has expired.

Instead of forking out the cash, I would like to use the MySQL Connector / Net and replace all instances of DotConnect with instances of MySQL Connector / Net.

Can anyone help me with this task please?

Comment: I'm actually going the other way (Connector/NET to dotConnect) for licensing reasons.  One difference i've noticed is that BIT columns come back in result sets as '0' and '1' values with Connector/NET, whereas with dotConnect they come back as 'False' and 'True'.  Did you notice/have any issues with this?  I'm wondering if there is a way to force dotConnect to return '0' and '1' for BIT columns in result sets..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to install everything on entirely new computer. Then I imported the source code files and did a find/replace to replace all references from the old connector to the new one. Turns out visual studio is picky. Depending on your 'References' you may have issues if your version of MS Office doesn't match the source code.

Good luck if you're having the same issue.. smh :/